# How to check if form shipping address in checkout is valid

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4

**When I do in checkout, I got an error :**
I would like to detect if the person has filled in the registration form in the checkout, this code is added in this file : app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/Amasty_CheckoutCore/templates/onepage.phtml

```
define(['jquery','mage/translate', 'mage/validation'], function($){
    "use strict";
    return {
        customMain: function (){

            console.log($('.form-shipping-address').validation('isValid'))


        }
    }
});
```

**error :**

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on validation prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isValid'

Comment: Magento default support validates the shipping address form. What are you trying to do? Could you describe it in more detail?

Comment: @TuVan I would like to add an extra step in full javascript, and then I have to activate or deactivate a button by checking if the form is well filled or not

Comment: Could you add the related xml, JS file, and a screenshot on the checkout page?

Comment: @TuVan I updated the code, I added the code in this file : app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/Amasty_CheckoutCore/templates/onepage.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside **require** and load **mage/validation**

```
require([
'jquery',
'mage/validation'
], function($){
   
   // Place your other code here

   console.log($('.form-shipping-address').validation('isValid'))

 
});
```

Comment: this is what I did

Comment: It puts an error in the console

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `validation()` function before use `isValid`.

Use this code to validate the shipping form:

```
var shippingForm = $('#co-shipping-form');
if (shippingForm.validation() && shippingForm.validation('isValid')) {
    console.log('valid');
} else {
    console.log('invalid');
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution in a setInterval, but console say valid while the form is not completed, don't understand why

Comment: I tried also shippingForm.validate(), it does not detect errors

Comment: Ok, let me check.